# Matching and DiD - understanding of the control group

Tags: r, difference-in-difference, matching

Im trying to understand the methodology of matching and how to matches are used in this article.

Specifically, are treated firms compared the WHOLE group of matched firms (ie all firms that got assigned to a treated firm as a match), or are the treated firms only compared to the one specific assigned match in the regression?

[Article, section 6.1.2 = matching & 6.1.3 = difference in difference regression](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jfineco.2021.01.010)

Comment: As an aside, if the matching excluded any valid data, watch out for inefficiency and non-reproducibility.

Comment: @FrankHarrell what do you mean?

Comment: Most matching algorithms do not go to the work of n:m matching for variable n and m with reuse of controls that happen to be good matches to multiple cases.  The result is that perfectly good controls are not used, resulting in inefficiency from the reduction in sample size. Any method that discards perfectly good data is suspect and creates inefficiencies.

Comment: @thomas.diridondo would you mind re-posting the article you asked the question about? The link you provided doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I have updated the link to a persistent DOI.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/331009)

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence of section 6.1.3 says

> To examine how firm-level outcomes evolve following the issuance of
> corporate green bonds, I estimate a difference-in-differences
> specification using all firm-year observations of the treated and
> matched control firms from 2010-2018.

This implies that they performed a difference-in-difference analysis in the matched set, i.e., discarding all control units that were not matched to a treated unit. It looks like they ignored pair membership in the analysis and treated the matched groups as independent samples, i.e., as if the treated and the matched controls were the only units in the study but had been sampled without a matched pair structure.

Note that retaining the matched structure would not have changed the effect estimate, in the same way a matched pairs t-test and an independent samples t-test test the same hypothesis and use the same sufficient statistic (i.e., the difference in means). So interpreting the results of the study doesn't depend on the answer to your question; the effect would be the same regardless.

Comment: Alright, I will try to rephrase to see if I understand your feedback. 

(1) the author creates a pool of matched control firms that do not get treatment. And discard all potential controls that were not assigned as a match to any treated firm. 
(2) the author ignores the matched pairs, i.e: rather than comparing the treated company A to its specific match A*, Treated company B to matched company B* etc, she compares A,B,C to A*,B*,C*. In other words run a DiD comparing treated vs matched control group
(3)using the approach mentioned above would give same results as matched pairs

Comment: Yes, that is a good rephrasing of my answer and what I believe to be true based on my reading of the paper.